# Nested for loop in C not working as expected

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
for (i = 2; i < input; i++){
    for (d = 2; d < input; d++){
        product = d*i;
        printf("%d\n", product);
        break;
    }
}
```

This snippet of code is part of my solution to a homework question for my Intro to C class. The actual question is something involving prime numbers, but the solution that I thought of requires the use of for loops nested like this. I can't get them to behave correctly, though. I assume using an array would simplify things, but we haven't taken them up yet and are not allowed to use them in our solution. Anyway:

If, for example, my input is 10, my values of `i` should be {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. My values for `d` should also be {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

What I expect this loop to do is multiply each `i` by the full loop of `d`:

```
2*2
2*3
2*4
.
.
.
2*9
3*2
3*3
.
.
.
.
```

and onwards. However, it is instead just multiplying `i` by `d = 2`, and I get the following:

```
4
6
8
10
.
.
.
20
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's because you `break;` the inner loop so it's only executed once...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  I've improved the presentation of the data by removing the blank lines and then selecting the data lines and using the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the data by 4 spaces, which puts it into constant-width font and highlights it, as shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (d = 2; d < input; d++){
        product = d*i;
        printf("%d\n", product);
        break;  // because of this line the loop breaks on first iteration.
}
```

Remove `break;` from  your code and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everybody. Can't believe I missed such a stupid mistake. Sorry for the poor formatting!

Answer (score 4):

Your `break` statement makes the inner loop run only once.  So you only multiply `i` by `d=2`.

You probably want this:

```
for (i = 2; i < input; i++){
    for (d = 2; d < input; d++){
        product = d*i;
        printf("%d\n", product);
        // break; this statement is causing you to exit loop after 1 iteration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

cut the `break;`, it's exiting your inner loop

essentially, the `break` statement turns the following `for` loop

```
for (d = 2; d < input; d++){
```

into an `if` statement

Comment: It's not really even an `if` statement, is it?  It's converting it into two sequential statements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but what if `input` is less than or equal to 2?

Comment: Then the outer loop will have exited first...?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `break;` line.  When your code gets here (on the first iteration), the inner loop (`d=2`...) will be skipped out of.

For statements aren't like switch statements where you need to end with `break;`.  You use a `break` statement to exit the loop not continue to the next iteration (that's what `continue` is for).